# No handlers could be found for logger "dajaxice"

Tags: python, django, logging, dajaxice

How do you setup the logger properly?

I was adding the logger after django's default one.

```
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
   'dajaxice': {
       'handlers': ['fileHandlerDajaxice'],
       'level': 'DEBUG',
       'propagate': False,
   },
```

But it doesn't work.
I changed them to logger as 'dajaxice.DajaxiceRequest', and while handlers stays the same. I tried many other different combinations and none work.

For example,

```
ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'dajaxice.DajaxiceRequest': Unable to add handler 'fileHandlerDajaxice': 'fileHandlerDajaxice'

ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'dajaxice': Unable to add handler 'dajaxice': 'dajaxice'
```

Reference, I was following this [reference](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dajaxproject/PoQ6w85yfYY/Xy_kunmgSK0J)

Answer (score 2):

In order to log `dajaxice`output you should add a new logger named `dajaxice` with the list of handlers you want to use.

```
LOGGING = {
    ...

    'loggers': {
        ...

        'dajaxice': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Your code already have this logger, but it seem to be failing because `fileHandlerDajaxice`.
Can you please post this part?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a handler under the key `'fileHandlerDajaxice'` (or whatever name you use in the `'handlers': [...]` line for the `'dajaxice'` logger.